# Is there a way to configure IntelliJ IDEA to keep comments when executing SQL?

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, ssms

My team is using SQL Server 2012, and we have been using MS SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  Some of us are beginning to use IntelliJ IDEA (currently on 2016.1.4).

We are required to keep a comment block in our stored procedures. In SSMS, we put this comment block directly above the ALTER PROCEDURE line, like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Comments here    
ALTER PROCEDURE ...
AS
BEGIN
...
GO
```

From my understanding (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993025/how-does-management-studio-know-to-save-my-t-sql-comments)), SQL Server saves our comments because the comments are inside a batch and GO is a batch terminator.

It seems like IntelliJ IDEA strips out comments before executing the statement, so these comments are removed from the stored procedures every time we execute a script from within IDEA.  We are able to view the comments in IDEA when we open a stored procedure, but they are gone when we look at the same procedure using SSMS.

Is there any way to save the comments when we execute the statement in IDEA?

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to put this comment inside the procedure rather than outside it? You know, right after the list of parameters. This way, you would not depend on the tool you use (and IDEA isn't the only one that applies this kind of "optimisation").

Comment: While it would work that way, we already have many stored procedures that are formatted with comments above the ALTER line, and the current SQL Server Stored Procedure guidelines for our company have it formatted this way. We'd like to have the comments before the ALTER line because there are often variables immediately following the ALTER line which would force the comments to be even further down, and we'd like these comments to be as close to the top as possible.